# Passing node name created runtime to xsl:value-of select

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

My Input XML :

```
<Book>
    <Chapter>
        <Pages value="20" />
        <Note1Code value="1" />
        <Note1Description value="This is just for reference" />
        <Note1Level value="Avg" />

        <Note2Code value="2" />
        <Note2Description value="This is high important note" />
        <Note2Level value="Imp" />
    </Chapter>
</Book>
```

I want to transform into :

```
<Book>
    <Chapter>
        <Pages value="20" />

        <Note>
            <Code>1</Code>
            <Description>This is just for reference</Description>
            <Level>Avg</Level>
        </Note

        <Note>
            <Code>2</Code>
            <Description>This is high important note</Description>
            <Level>Imp</Level>
        </Note  
    </Chapter>
</Book>
```

Here is my XSLT :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[substring(name(), 1, 4) = 'Note' and substring(name(),6) = 'Code']">

        <xsl:variable name="pdIdx" select="substring(name(), 5, 1)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="pdNode" select="concat('Note',$pdIdx,'Description/@value')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="pd" select="$pdNode"/>
        <Code>
            <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
        </Code>
        <Description>
            <xsl:value-of select="$pdNode"/>
        </Description>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am trying to create the node name dynamically and then trying to get the value in select attribute. However, it is not working. The output is : The description tag is taking the node name and not its value

```
<Book>
    <Chapter>
        <Pages value="20"/>

        <Code>1</Code>
<Description>Note1Description/@value</Description>
        <Node1Description value="This is just for reference"/>
        <Note1Level value="Avg"/>

        <Code>2</Code>
<Description>Note2Description/@value</Description>
        <Node2Description value="This is high important note"/>
        <Note2Level value="Imp"/>
    </Chapter>
</Book>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks a little messed up, but I believe would do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:key name="elements" match="*" use="name()"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'Note')   
                        and
                        substring(name(),string-length(name())-3) = 'Code'
                        and
                        number(substring-before(substring-after(name(),'Note'),'Code'))]">

    <xsl:variable name="Num" select="number(substring-before(substring-after(name(),'Note'),'Code'))"/>
    <Note>
        <Code><xsl:value-of select="key('elements', concat('Note',$Num,'Code'))/@value"/></Code>
        <Description><xsl:value-of select="key('elements', concat('Note',$Num,'Description'))/@value"/></Description>
        <Level><xsl:value-of select="key('elements', concat('Note',$Num,'Level'))/@value"/></Level>
    </Note>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'Note')   
                        and
                            ((substring(name(),string-length(name())-10) = 'Description'
                            and
                            number(substring-before(substring-after(name(),'Note'),'Description'))) 

                                or (substring(name(),string-length(name())-4) = 'Level'
                            and
                            number(substring-before(substring-after(name(),'Note'),'Level'))))
                        ]"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: plus one for nice code, which can be suitable to all formats of inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Few changes I made in your code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[contains(name(), 'Note') and contains(name(), 'Code')]">

        <xsl:variable name="pdIdx" select="translate(name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="pdNode" select="following-sibling::*[contains(name(), concat('Note',$pdIdx,'Description'))]/@value"/>
        <xsl:variable name="pdLevel" select="following-sibling::*[contains(name(), concat('Note',$pdIdx,'Level'))]/@value"/>
        <xsl:variable name="pd" select="$pdNode"/>
      <Note>
        <Code>
            <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
        </Code>
        <Description>
            <xsl:value-of select="$pdNode"/>
        </Description>
        <Level>
            <xsl:value-of select="$pdLevel"/>
        </Level>
      </Note>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[contains(name(), 'Description')]"/>
    <xsl:template match="*[contains(name(), 'Level')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Rudramuni. Nearly there but while using in eclipse , getting the following error :11:53:41,432 ERROR [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(matches, [funcall(name, []), funcall(concat, [literal-expr(Note), variable-ref(pdIdx/string), literal-expr(Description)])])'.

Comment: @RudramuniTP I'm afraid you are using functions(_matches()_) not supported in XPath1.0 but 2.0.

Comment: @Gaurav, updated by replacing 'matches' to 'contains', check now.

Comment: @Gaurav Won't the numbers in element names go 2 digits(e.g., `<Note10Code>`? This would fail the code.

Comment: Good catch @LingamurthyCS .. So how can I deal with this ?. Using regex ??

Comment: @Gaurav, <xsl:template match="*[substring(name(), 1, 4) = 'Note' and substring(name(),6) = 'Code']"> can be change to <xsl:template match="*[contains(name(), 'Note') and contains(name(), 'Code')]">.

Comment: @RudramuniTP `contains` may not work in cases where the element is `<NoteXYZCode>`, and if the requirement is really to process only element names having number between _Note_ and _Code_.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't this be simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'Note') and contains(name(), 'Code')]" priority="1">
    <Note>
        <Code>
            <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
        </Code>
        <Description>
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]/@value"/>
        </Description>
        <Level>
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[2]/@value"/>
        </Level>
    </Note>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'Note')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

This *is* assuming there aren't elements whose name starts with "Note" elsewhere in the source document.